If A is connected, then so is it's interior (proof check)
This is a common question that has been asked several times (e.g. here) and the statement does not hold true. (Common counter example is 2 discs which touch at a boundary giving a connected union but disconnected interior.)
However, I have "proved" otherwise and I cannot workout why my proof is wrong. Can someone please enlighten me as to where I have made an error?
The definition of connectedness that I am working with is that a topological space $X$ is connected if the only subsets that are both open and closed are $ \emptyset $ and $X$. The question I am answering has $A$ as a subset of a topological space $X$.
Proof:
Assume for contradiction that A is connected but the interior of A is disconnected. Then there exists some $Z \subset A^\mathrm{o}$ which is both open and closed with $ Z \neq \emptyset, A^\mathrm{o}$.
But $Z \subset A^\mathrm{o} \subset A$, so we have a set in $A$ which is both open and closed contradicting connectedness of $A$.
My only guess is that given definition is for whole space $X$ and not a subspace $A$.

Why is $Z$ closed in $A$? You only know that it is closed in the subspace topology of the interior of $A$.

If you look at your example with the touching balls you can see that things go wrong. Pick $Z$ to be the interior of one of the balls.

Ah, I was working under the assumption that if $Z$ is closed and open subset of $A^\mathrm{o}$, then since $A^\mathrm{o} \subset A$, $Z$ must be closed and open subset of $A$.
Is this not the case because open (and closed) sets in the subspace topology of $A^\mathrm{o}$ are not necessarily open (and closed) subsets of the subspace topology of $A$?
E.g. Z being the interior of one of the balls is clopen with respect to the interior of the two balls, but certainly not closed with respect to the 2 full discs?

That's exactly the problem.

The problem is that "$Z$ is closed in $\dot{A}$" does not imply "$Z$ is closed in $A$".
Consider your counterexample $A=\overline{B((0,0),1)}\cup \overline{B((2,0),1)}$ with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean topology.
The interior is given by $\dot{A}=B((0,0),1)\cup B((2,0),1)$. Now if we pick $Z=B((0,0),1)$, then $Z$ is both open and closed in $\dot{A}$, however, it is not closed in $A$.
